# (Cross-)Compiling Swift for Raspberry PI

Tags: swift, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

Swift is now Open Source. Did anyone tried compiling Swift for a Raspberry PI? I started to do, but my 8 GB SD card seems to be too small for it ;) Is it possible to cross compile it from Ubuntu?

Comment: 8gb too small? can you elaborate on that? Even iOS doesn't take up 8gb.

Comment: For compiling... There was an error "fatal error: error in backend: IO failure on output stream."

Comment: Yup that seems to be an out-of-disk-space error. Some people on the interwebs had some succes with a reboot. Can you compile to a different location and check the resulting size?

Comment: I now compiled with Xubuntu... the complete folder had 6.9 GB. I retry it with a Rasbian lite, but I think it will not work... swift.org says: "Currently x86_64 is the only supported architecture on Linux."

Comment: Did you say you got it to compile? I have been trying to get it to compile (64G card) but haven't been able to get it to work (compiles for 24h then errors). How are you doing it?

Comment: No, I just could compile it with Xubuntu. With Raspberry I also get errors (firstly because of lacking space)

Comment: Andrew Madsen has compiled it. Here is the link to his blog: http://blog.andrewmadsen.com/post/136137396480/swift-on-raspberry-pi Have not tried it myself due to lack of a free SD Card, but it does look promising

Comment: @Lupurus: If the problem is really lack os disk space, you may attach an external HD (USB) or map a network disk and use PREFIX to compile and store the compiled objects on the new disk.

Answer (score 7):

A 8GB SD Card works ok, but you'll need to extend the root volume. I have it working and the used space on `/dev/root` partition is around 3.1GB.

The steps below are based on the blog post by [Andrew Madsen](http://blog.andrewmadsen.com/post/136137396480/swift-on-raspberry-pi) with a little extra focus on the steps inside `fdisk`.

### Get Ubuntu

Download an image of Ubuntu 14.04 for Raspberry Pi 2 from  [finnie.org](http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/2015-04-06-ubuntu-trusty.zip) and copy it onto the SD card. Boot the Raspberry Pi.

### Change the partition

Log into the Raspberry Pi and change the partition size. The default size for `/dev/root` is 1.7G with 1.1G available. That is not enough.

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       1.7G  540M  1.1G  35% /
devtmpfs        458M  4.0K  458M   1% /dev
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             93M  228K   93M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            462M     0  462M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mmcblk0p1   64M   20M   45M  31% /boot/firmware
```

Run fdisk

```
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
```

At the prompt enter `p` for 'print the partition table'. There are two partitions

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *        2048      133119       65536    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          133120     3670015     1768448   83  Linux
```

When prompted, enter `d` (for delete), then `2`. Then, recreate the partition by entering `n`, then `p`, then `2`, then pressing enter at the next two prompts accepting the defaults.

Enter `p` again and see the second partition is now bigger, now all space on an 8GB card is used.

```
           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *        2048      133119       65536    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          133120    15523839     7695360   83  Linux
```

Enter `w` to write the changes to disk, then reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

#### Resize the partition

After the reboot, resize the partition’s file system by running

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

#### Swap space

Setup a swap file by doing

```
sudo apt-get install dphys-swapfile
```

#### Install libicu-dev and clang-3.6

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev clang-3.6
```

Use update-alternatives to provide /usr/bin links for clang and clang++:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-3.6 100 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-3.6 100
```

Then, add @iachievedit’s repository key:

```
wget -qO- http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the appropriate repository to sources.list:

```
echo "deb [arch=armhf] http://iachievedit-repos.s3.amazonaws.com/ trusty main" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Run apt-get update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

### Install Swift

```
sudo apt-get install swift-2.2
```

After the installation is complete, you’re ready to compile Swift programs!

### Write Swift

Open your favorite text editor, write a program, and save it (e.g. to 'hello.swift’):

```
let device = "Raspberry Pi 2!" 
print("Hello from Swift on \(device)")
```

#### Compile it

```
swiftc hello.swift
```

and run it:

```
./hello

Hello from Swift on Raspberry Pi 2!
```

That’s it! Swift running on Raspberry Pi

Comment: Good to know there's a pre-compiled package already. Are/Were you able to confirm it's trustworthy? - http://dev.iachieved.it claims to own that bucket. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: I have decided to trust it for now :) On the above referenced blog it says: `William Dillon (@hpux735) announced that he had gotten the Swift compiler to successfully build for armv7 systems such as the BeagleBone, Raspberry Pi 2, etc. A while later, @iachievedit had packaged William’s work up and made it available via apt-get for Debian and Ubuntu.`

Comment: An answer on how really *cross*-compile it would be nice (e.g. build on OS X, deploy on Rasperry Pi).

Comment: Excellent answer. Do you know if it's possible to install clang and Swift on Raspian, or does it only work with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

The Swift Package Manager got custom toolchain support via
[PR-1098](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/1098)
end of April 2017.

I wrote up detailed instructions on how to build a RaspberryPi toolchain over here: [macOS -> RasPi Cross Compilation Toolchain](https://github.com/helje5/dockSwiftOnARM/tree/master/toolchain)
and even the reverse ([build macOS binaries on a RaspberryPi](https://github.com/helje5/dockSwiftOnARM/blob/master/toolchain/macosx/README.md)) for the fun of it.
The same would work for Intel-Linux to ARM-Linux w/ minimal modifications. The SwiftPM repo contains an [example script](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Utilities/build_ubuntu_cross_compilation_toolchain) on how to do this for Intel-macOS to Intel-Ubuntu.

You can find a 2017-05-01 update on Swift-on-ARM over here:
[An Update on Swift 3.1.1 For Raspberry Pi Zero/1/2/3](https://www.uraimo.com/2017/05/01/An-update-on-Swift-3-1-1-for-raspberry-pi-zero-1-2-3/).

As a small summary, so that this answer isn't just links ;-), ARM status 2017-05-16:

- you can compile Swift 3.1/3.1.1 on RaspberryPi Ubuntu

  - don't forget to setup swap, some minimal patches are required 
    for 3.1.1. 8GB disk may be a bit to little.
- compilation on Raspbian doesn't seem to work yet (last known version
  is 3.0.2)
- you can cross-compile Swift using a custom toolchain, which is
  reasonably easy to setup

  - you need to grab a SwiftPM snapshot (Swift 4) for this (but the toolchain itself can be 3.1 or even 3.0.2 w/ minor changes)
- you can also run (and compile) [Swift via Docker](https://github.com/helje5/dockSwiftOnARM/blob/master/README.md),
  e.g. in HypriotOS.
- there is a Slack group for Swift ARM: `swift-arm`