# How to build a swift executable for Linux on macOS

Tags: swift, linux, macos, compilation, cross-compiling

I am trying to build a swift executable on my MacBook for my Linux vServer.

I already tried using `swiftc -target "x86_64-linux test.swift`, but my macOS swift compiler shows this error: `<unknown>:0: error: unable to load standard library for target 'x86_64--linux'`

So I looked around and found this question: [Swift on OS X compiling for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041483/swift-on-os-x-compiling-for-linux) and tried out this [example script](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Utilities/build_ubuntu_cross_compilation_toolchain) from apple to setup a cross-platform toolchain.

After trying to build a module like shown in the example text of the script, it compiled, but on my linux machine I now get this error: `error while loading shared libraries: libswiftCore.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` which is strange, because swift is properly installed on my Linux machine and works.

So have I done anything wrong while cross-compiling the project, or is there a problem on my Linux machine? Also I wonder, if there is a more simple way of compiling a project for Linux on macOS, like changing the Build Settings in Xcode or something?

Thanks in advance,
Jonas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This just means it couldn't locate the linked library. If your `libswiftCore.so` located at `/usr/lib/swift/linux` you can run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/swift/linux ./<your executable for linux>` and it will work like a charm.

You can also set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to just execute the binary.

Comment: Sure there is no typo in the command you wrote? `LD_LIBRARY_PATH/usr/lib/swift/linux` is not a valid command on my machine.

`-bash: LD_LIBRARY_PATH/usr/lib/swift/linux: No such file or directory`

Comment: Never mind. Got it. There is a `=` missing between your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and the folder. Thanks a lot! It worked :)